# Intellij IDEA Java/Scala project subpackage display

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, package, visualization

In Intellij Idea, in Project window where the Java/Scala packages hierarchy is displayed, how to visualise a specific subpackage only ? Namely, how to trim some prefixes in the package tree ?

**Update**

In a similar way as in Eclipse 'Goto...' option on packages display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking about but if you want to trim middle packages you should select Compact Empty / Middle Packages (project view context menu).